# How to connect to Azure Synapse SQL via proxy using oAuth token?

Tags: proxy, azure-sql-database, connection-string, ssh-tunnel

So the issue is SSH tunnel and oAuth token. Without tunnel it works just fine using connection string:

```
sqlsrv:server=tcp:[WORKSPACE].database.windows.net,1433;Database=[DB];AccessToken=[TOKEN]
```

But if I try to connect via

```
ssh -f -L 12345:[WORKSPACE].database.windows.net:1433 proxy@proxy-domain.com -p 22 -i \/config\/path -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no sleep 60 >> \/tmp\/logfile
```

And then

```
sqlsrv:server=tcp:127.0.0.1,12345;Database=[DB];AccessToken=[TOKEN]
```

I get

> QLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:subject name does not match host name]

Also tried adding `TrustServerCertificate=yes` to the connection string, but same error. Adding also `Encrypt=yes` gives this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server "127.0.0.1" requested by the login.  The login failed.

I believe this is because token has *Audience*: https://sql.azuresynapse.net, but I try to connect to `127.0.0.1`? Or am I thinking wrong here?

Tried changing DB firewall config on portal.azure.com Connection Policy to Proxy, but didn't help. Maybe I should change App Authentication settings to something? It's a multi-tenant app.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Could you please help where you are  trying to make the connection if it is a linked service in Azure Synapse or something else.

Comment: Something else. Authorization happens via a multi-tenant app where I get the token. Then I try to connect via proxy from outside of Azure

Comment: Sorry, but wanted to know your setup to understand the environment in order to repro it, could you please help if you are using AAD or On-premises AD

Comment: It's AAD. Requests are executed from our own servers

Comment: Thank you for letting me know its AAD, Could you please help on understanding your client tool which is trying to make the connection with Azure Synapse SQL. It would be great if you can share detailed steps or snippets. So, we could help with a repro.